# Inner measure and outer measure

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E\subset[a,b]$ be a non-mensurable set.
I want to show that:

$\exists  F \in F_\sigma$ : $F\subset E$ , $\mu^*(F)=\mu_*(E)$ .

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularity_theorem_for_Lebesgue_measure

Comment: @user32240 The set $E$ here is non-measurable. And Avril, what measure are we talking about here, the Lebesgue measure? Also, how did you define the inner measure in you class?